# Rails is missing test/unit. Where is it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, ruby-on-rails-4

I am following along with the book Jump Start Rails 4, and I am told to add some validation to the test/unit/post_test.rb file. However, my app is missing the unit folder. And for some reason ALL of the other apps on my computer are missing the unit folder as well. Does anyone know why and how to fix this?

Comment: The correct file path would be `test/models/post_test.rb`.

Comment: Thank you. Sorry for the late response. But I did find it where you said to look.

Comment: Awesome! I added the same in an answer for others' benefit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `rails 4` versions, the test folders are changed from the previous versions as follows:

`test/unit/` => `test/models/`

`test/functional/` => `test/controllers`